# Graphing Functions and invertibility

Tags: functions

[image]

So here's the problem:The complete graph of $y=f(x),$ which consists of five line segments, is shown in red below. (On this graph, the distance between grid lines is $1.$)

Let $a$ and $b$ be the largest negative integer and the smallest positive integer, respectively, such that the functions $g(x)=f(x)+ax$ and $h(x)=f(x)+bx$ are invertible. What is $a^2+b^2?$

So obviously this graph isn't invertible (using the horizantal line test). But how do I make it invertible? Any help would be great.

Comment: Stop cheating in AoPS! We can permanently ban you from violating our Honor Code!!!

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)$ itself isn't invertible, but if you add a function to it that increases faster than it ever decreases, or decreases faster than it ever increases, then the rises and drops of $f(x)$ are not enough to make the sum function change directions. So the sum would still be invertible.

So you just have to figure out how fast that $ax$ has to fall, and $bx$ has to rise to overcome the reversals in $f(x)$. For that, note that if you have two lines $y = m_1x + b_1$ and $y = m_2x+b_2$, then their sum is the line $$y = (m_1+m_2)x + (b_1+b_2)$$ What is required of that sum for it to be invertible?

Comment: I still can not understand this problem. Could you explain further?

Comment: @djdumpling - Though I wonder about it, the comment from user813242 concerns me. If this a test question for an online course that you are supposed to do yourself, know that I have no intention of helping you cheat. (If it is just a homework problem, then my concern is about the program). I will say this: look at the graph. Why is it not invertible? What would the graph an invertible piecewise linear function look like? Write out the equation for $$f(x) = \begin{cases} \ldots, & x \le -2\\\ldots, &-2 < x \le -1\\\ldots,&\ldots\end{cases}$$ what happens if you add $ax$ or subtract $bx$ from it?

Comment: I actually figured it out yesterday. But thank you for the help. As for the question itself, it was a homework problem. Sorry about that.

Comment: @djdumpling - Glad you figured it out on your own - that is always better. Now I am concerned about the course - homework is intended to give the student practice in handling the concepts, not to measure their ability Seeking help with homework is common and reasonable. For an instructor or other official to call it cheating is rather extreme.

Comment: Sorry, I apologize about that.

Comment: @djdumpling - why? Are you user813242? Otherwise, I don't see anything for which you bear responsibility.

Comment: No, I am not. I just got a little confused, that is all. :)